# How to web page content dynamically sharing on google+?

Tags: google-plus

I have website content share on google+. But content sharing on static not sharing on dynamically.

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<meta itemprop="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $site; ?>">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />

 <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><span>Google+</span></a>
```

Comment: Your question looks confusing. Please re-write it providing more info on what you're trying to do and what's the problem.

Comment: I have share title, description, image on dynamically using meta tag. But not working google + sharing. Only shared static content.